# Apache Tuning query

Tags: apache-http-server

I am trying to tune the parameters in apache for a high traffic website. 
My specs are

```
Ram : 12 GB RAM
CPU : 16 core
```

Current Parameters

```
StartServers 5
MinSpareServers 5
MaxSpareServers 10
MinSpareServers 5
MaxSpareServers 10
ServerLimit 2500
MaxClients 2500
MaxRequestsPerChild 10000
KeepAlive Off
KeepAliveTimeout 5
MaxKeepAliveRequests 100
```

What is the advised values for this parameters according to my server specs?

Comment: Why do you have duplicated settings in there?

Answer (score 1):

There is a great tutorial [on this site](http://dasunhegoda.com/configure-apache-multi-processing-modules-mpms/531/) how to "calculate" the settings.
(Tutorial also below in case the site goes offline)

> Before customising the directives you need to understand how the
>   directives work. Let me explain in plain English. Server will start 2
>   child processes which is determined by StartServers directive. Each
>   process will start 20 threads which is determined by ThreadsPerChild
>   directive so this means 2 process can service only 40 concurrent
>   connections/clients(i.e. 20×2=40). So what if more requests come in.
>
> Now if more concurrent users come, then another child process will
>   start, that can serve another 20 users. But how many child processes
>   can be started is controlled by ServerLimit parameter, this means that
>   in the configuration above, I can have 10 child processes in total,
>   with each child process can handle 20 thread, in total handling
>   10×20=200 concurrent users.
>
> But there is a problem, number defined in MaxClients is 100 here, this
>   means that after 5 child processes, no extra process will start since
>   we have defined an upper cap of MaxClients. This also means that if I
>   set MaxClients to 500, after 10 child processes and 200 connections,
>   no extra process will start and we cannot service more than 200
>   concurrent clients even if we have increase the MaxClient parameter.
>   In this case, we need to also increase ServerLimit to 500/20 i.e.
>   MaxClients/ThreadsPerChild=25
>
> Okay now you know the directives and how they work, the problem is how
>   to calculate the directives. Let’s jump into calculating directive
>   values.
>
> You can use this shell script to determine an average amount of memory
>   consumed by one Apache process. In addition to that it’ll show total
>   amount of memory consumed by all Apache processes. Just unzip and
>   execute with sh command. Accurate results will be shown when server is
>   under heavy load.
>
> The output
>
> Apache Memory Usage (MB): 57.586 Average Proccess Size (MB): 10.2
>
> ```
> Apache Memory Usage (MB): 57.586
> Average Proccess Size (MB): 10.2
> ```
>
> if in average, let’s assume that one Apache process consumes 50MB RAM
>   and server has got RAM is 2048MB, and you want to leave 512MB for the
>   rest of the processes, then:
>
> ```
> MaxClients = (2048MB – 512MB)/10MB = 153.6 ~ 153
> ```